# NameError: global name 'User' is not defined?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite, web

here is the way i create a user:

```
if form.validate():
        flash('Thanks for registration ' + name)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()

        user = User(name,password,coins)
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()
    else:
        flash('Error: All the form fields are required. ')
```

Traceback says that NameError: global name 'User' is not defined, and points to this:

```
user = User(name,password,coins)
```

I use SQLite3, and the database table is called "User", so... i don't know what the problem is!

My imports are:

```
import os

import sys

import pprint

from flask import Markup

from flask import redirect, url_for, session

from flask import redirect, render_template, request, session, abort

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from tabledef import *

from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request

from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators,

StringField, SubmitField

import sqlite3 as lite
```

sorry thats its a bit messy...

Comment: show your `import` section.

Comment: Can you please add your imports in the question itself ?

Comment: and where you do import or declare the `User`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is since you haven't imported User. Hope it works.

```
from models import User
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named models

Comment: I thought it was flask. Anyway you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i figured it out.. Thanks guys! 
I needed to import the python script where i define User().
Rookie mistake sry...